# python to extract list match from email thread

Tags: python, regex, match

I m new to python. I need to retrieve the list of match

for Example my text is below which is an email.
I need to extract all To, From, Sent, Subject and body from a mail thread.

Result need to From List

From(1) = Crandall, Sean 
From(2) = Nettelton, Marcus

To(1)= Crandall, Sean; Badeer, Robert
To(2)= Meredith, Kevin

Like for above Sent, subject etc

```
"-----Original Message-----
From:   Crandall, Sean  
Sent:   Wednesday, May 23, 2001 2:56 PM
To: Meredith, Kevin
Subject:    RE: Spreads and Product long desc.

Kevin,

Is the SP and NP language in the spread language the same language we use when we transact SP15 or NP15 on eol?

 -----Original Message-----
From:   Meredith, Kevin  
Sent:   Wednesday, May 23, 2001 11:16 AM
To: Crandall, Sean; Badeer, Robert
Subject:    FW: Spreads and Product long desc."
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.findall()` for this, see: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall. E.g.

```
re.findall("From:   (.*)  ", input_string);
```

would return a list of the From-names (`['Crandall, Sean', 'Meredith, Kevin']`), assuming it's always the same amount of white spaces.

If you want to get fancy, you could do several searches in the same expression: E.g.

```
re.findall("From:   (.*)  \nSent:   (.*)", input_string);
```

would return `[('Crandall, Sean', 'Wednesday, May 23, 2001 2:56 PM'), ('Meredith, Kevin', 'Wednesday, May 23, 2001 11:16 AM')]`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know how to use regex and as your problem is not that tough, you may consider to use the `split()` and `replace()` functions.

Here are some lines of code that might be a good start:

```
mails = """-----Original Message-----
From:   Crandall, Sean  
Sent:   Wednesday, May 23, 2001 2:56 PM
To: Meredith, Kevin
Subject:    RE: Spreads and Product long desc.

Kevin,

Is the SP and NP language in the spread language the same language we use when we transact SP15 or NP15 on eol?

 -----Original Message-----
From:   Meredith, Kevin  
Sent:   Wednesday, May 23, 2001 11:16 AM
To: Crandall, Sean; Badeer, Robert
Subject:    FW: Spreads and Product long desc."""

mails_list = mails.split("-----Original Message-----\n")
mails_from = []
mails_sent = []
mails_to = []
mails_subject = []
mails_body = []

for mail in mails_list:
    if not mail:
        continue
    inter = mail.split("From:   ")[1].split("\nSent:   ")
    mails_from.append(inter[0])
    inter = inter[1].split("\nTo: ")
    mails_sent.append(inter[0])
    inter = inter[1].split("\nSubject:    ")
    mails_to.append(inter[0])
    inter = inter[1].split("\n")
    mails_subject.append(inter[0])
    mails_body.append(inter[0])
```

See how this only use really basic concepts.

Here are some points that you might need to consider:

- Try by yourself, you might need some adjustments.
- With that method, the parsing method is quite tough, the format of the mails must be really accurate.
- There might be some space that you want to remove, for example with the `replace()` method.